# combine an array of object by id and and reduce its nested object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects (old_array) that needs to be merged to become (new_array)

```
old_array = [
        { id: 'ffff55', name: 'f5', card: 'a', request: { device: 0, bus: 1, ship: 21 } },
        { id: 'vvvv44', name: 'v4', card: 'c', request: { device: 3, bus: 10, ship: 2 } },
        { id: 'cccc33', name: 'c3', card: 'a', request: { device: 0, bus: 1, ship: 2 } },
        { id: 'ffff55', name: 'f5', card: 'b', request: { device: 32, bus: 31, ship: 32 } },
        { id: 'cccc33', name: 'c3', card: 'e', request: { device: 21, bus: 21, ship: 22 } },
        { id: 'cccc33', name: 'c3', card: 'd', request: { device: 4, bus: 1, ship: 2 } },
        { id: 'vvvv44', name: 'v4', card: 'c', request: { device: 13, bus: 11, ship: 12 } }
    ];

new_array = [
        { id: 'ffff55', name: 'f5', unique_cards: 2, request: { device: 32, bus: 32, ship: 53 } },
        { id: 'vvvv44', name: 'v4', unique_cards: 1, request: { device: 16, bus: 21, ship: 14 } },
        { id: 'cccc33', name: 'c3', unique_cards: 3, request: { device: 25, bus: 23, ship: 26 } }
    ];
```

- merge the objects with same id and name to a single object
- merge the nested request object (Sum of its values)
- map card to the number of unique cards (by id)

I've been trying for 4 days straight but this array manipulation was hard

My best attempt was trying to group the array of objects by id but it become more complex with many redundant values

```
groupByArray(xs, key) {
        return xs.reduce(function(rv, x) {
            let v = key instanceof Function ? key(x) : x[key];
            let el = rv.find((r) => r && r.key === v);
            if (el) {
                el.values.push(x);
            } else {
                rv.push({ key: v, values: [ x ] });
            }
            return rv;
        }, []);
    }

groupByArray(old_array , 'id')
```

Comment: show your best attempt in js

Comment: @zerkms i tried to group the arrays by id then mapping and reducing but it become more complex (more nested objects )

Comment: You have enumerated 3 different task. Try solve only the first one and publish your best attempt. That really is an EXTREMELY FREQUENT request here: at least make a research.

Comment: @zerkms i only ask if i'm very desperate . most of what i found about merging is either a simple array or using underscore.js loddah and other stuff. 14h straight today of searching

Comment: "is either a simple array" --- you have a simple array of simple objects. The problem here is that now you have an answer, yet you still are not able to solve such sort of tasks. You indeed can copy-paste it, but tomorrow you'll be stuck again when the conditions slightly change 

Comment: @zerkms I 'm open to explanation instead of a solution. i know how to use reduce, map. as soon as there is nested objects it gets confusing.

Comment: Try to simplify the first problem and solve it. If stuck - ask a more particular question. There is no some secret knowledge to be explained here really: you just iterate over an array and accumulate something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` to group and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

Inside of the reduce's handler, you need to loop over the request's keys in order to sum up each value.

```js
let array = [        { id: 'ffff55', name: 'f5', card: 'a', request: { device: 0, bus: 1, ship: 21 } },        { id: 'vvvv44', name: 'v4', card: 'c', request: { device: 3, bus: 10, ship: 2 } },        { id: 'cccc33', name: 'c3', card: 'a', request: { device: 0, bus: 1, ship: 2 } },        { id: 'ffff55', name: 'f5', card: 'b', request: { device: 32, bus: 31, ship: 32 } },        { id: 'cccc33', name: 'c3', card: 'e', request: { device: 21, bus: 21, ship: 22 } },        { id: 'cccc33', name: 'c3', card: 'd', request: { device: 4, bus: 1, ship: 2 } },        { id: 'vvvv44', name: 'v4', card: 'c', request: { device: 13, bus: 11, ship: 12 } }    ];
let result = Object.values(array.reduce((a, {id, name, card, request}) => {
  (a[id] || (a[id] = {id, card, name, unique_cards: 1, request: {}}));
  
  if (a[id].card !== card) {
    a[id].unique_cards++;
    a[id].card = card;
  }
  
  Object.keys(request).forEach(k => a[id].request[k] = (a[id].request[k] || 0) + request[k]); 
  return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

result.forEach(o => delete o.card);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @AmineDa. you're right, so you need to check for the last validated card's value to increase the counter.  See the updated answer, unfortunately, the last step should be loop the result and delete the `card` property.

Comment: @AmineDa. basically, I'm asking for a previously captured object by `id`.  So, If `a[id]` is different than undefined means that I got an object before so I need to work on it, otherwise, is a new id which I didn't get before, so I should create the desired object structure.

Comment: @.Ele one more thing. I don't get the point of a[id].card = card inside if

Comment: @AmineDa. this is like a breadcrumb, because I need to know if the previously checked card is different in order to increment the count.

Comment: yes, but we should check on the whole array of "a[id].card" not only the last value. if i add one more object to the array with an older card, it will count as unique